# Fetch the employee having no address?

Tags: database, oracle, join

I am new to database programming.

I have a database structure here.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1174

I want to Fetch all the employee having no address.

It should fetch employee with id as 3.

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do

```
select * from emp where id not in(select distinct(id) from address);
```

Comment: Yes! it works, but try to avoid sub queries, if you can achieve your target without sub query.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select * from emp as e
left join address as a on e.id=a.id
where a.id is null
```